# Hurricane Electric Tunnel with Pfsense?

Tags: ipv6, pfsense, tunneling

How would I setup a HE net Tunnel to route through PFsense so I can have v6 addresses on my servers? I already have the tunnel setup on their end, but there is no instructions for PFsense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note: These instructions appear to be incomplete. Read the full post before trying to follow this.

---

For over a year i have been using m0n0wall for its IPv6 connectivity. It isn't perfect, as m0n0wall still has a lot of IPv6 functionality missing (*e.g. traffic shaping*). But it does have [extraordinarily simple IPv6 Tunnel Broker setup](https://superuser.com/questions/317896/how-to-configure-monowall-to-use-tunnelbroker).

Now pfSense 2.1 has been released, with (hopefully) more IPv6 support than m0n0wall. On the other hand, the setup of an IPv6 tunnel is extraordinarily complicated. Now that i've spent three hours trying to make it work, i can finally document my results. It is filled with a lot out confusing, non-obvious, out-of-order, duplicated setup. Furthermore, there are still bugs that can cause your configuration to become invalid; requiring you to delete everything and start over.

Having said all that, here's how you configure IPv6 Hurricane Electric Tunnel Broker in pfSense.

### But first the confusing background

But before we can setup anything, we have to take a moment to realize something utterly confusing, non-obvious, non-intuitive:

> You do not send IPv6 traffic out your WAN connection

i have two network cards in my router:

> - **WAN**: (xl0, 3Com), connected to modem
> - **LAN**: (rl0, RealTek), connected to internal LAN hub

But IP (Internet Protocol) traffic does not go out my **WAN** `3Com` interface. My connection to the Internet is through DSL, which means my router uses PPPoE to connect to my ISP.

This means that pfSense creates another interface:

> - **WAN**: (PPPoE), connects through PPPoE tunnel to Internet
> - **OPT1**: (xl0, 3Com) connected to modem
> - **LAN**: (rl0, RealTek) connected to internal LAN hub

So my connection to the internet actually goes out this *virtual* interface. This becomes important, because only `IPv4` goes out this *"PPPoE"* interface.

In order to have **IPv6** support, we will actually be creating a **4th interface**; one that is dedicated to *only* IPv6 traffic:

> - **WAN**: (PPPoE), connects through PPPoE tunnel to Internet
> - **WANv6**: (HE_GW), connects through HE.net tunnel
> - **OPT1**: (xl0, 3Com) connected to modem
> - **LAN**: (rl0, RealTek) connected to internal LAN hub

## Your Tunnel info

First we need your tunnel information from your TunnelBroker page:

> **IPv6 Tunnel Endpoints**
>
> - Server IPv4 Address: 209.51.181.2
> - Server IPv6 Address: 2001:470:3c10:1178::1 /64
> - Client IPv6 Address: 2001:470:3c10:1178::2 /64
>
> **Routed IPv6 Prefixes**
>
> - Routed /64: 2001:470:3c11:1178:: /64

This first section are addresses related to your tunnel connection to Hurricane Electric (addresses that will be assocated with your WAN interface and gateways). The second section is your *"LAN"* addresses.

## Configuring pfSense 2.1 with a Hurricane Electric Tunnel Broker tunnel

**Create A New Tunnel Interface**

1. Under **Interfaces** -> **(assign)**, select the **GIF** tab, and click the **`+`** to add a new tunnel:

   [image]
2. Next configure the new **GIF** options:

   - **Parent interface**: `WAN`
   - **gif remote address**: `209.51.181.2` *(**Server IPv4 Address** from HE tunnel details page)*
   - **gif tunnel local address**: `2001:470:3c10:1178::2` *(**Client IPv6 Address** from HE tunnel details page)*
   - **gif remote tunnel address**: `2001:470:3c10:1178::1` `64` *(**Server IPv6 Address** from HE tunnel details page)*
   - **Description**: `HE.net IPv6 tunnel`

   [image]

   and click **Save**.

   Now your new **GIF** (*Generic Interface*) tunnel is configured:

   [image]

**Create a new IPv6 interface**

Now that we've created a tunnel, we are going to create a separate IPv6-only interface that will send traffic out that tunnel.

1. Under **Interfaces** -> **(assign)**, select the **Interface assignments** tab, and click the **`+`** to add a new interface:

   [image]

   **Note:** i happen to have an Atheros WiFi adapter, listed as `OPT1`. Don't let that confuse you.
2. In the drop-down for the newly added interface, select the previously created **`GIF 209.51.181.2 (HE.net IPv6 tunnel)**:

   [image]

   and click **Save**.
3. After the interface **`OPT2`** has been created, click it (either in the above list, or in the left menu under **Interfaces** -> **OPT2**.
4. Check **Enable interface** to reveal the configuration options:

   - **Description**: `WANv6` *(this is to differentiate it from your IPv4 WAN)*
   - **IPv6 Configuration Type**: `Static IPv6`
   - **IPv6 address**: `2001:470:3c10:1178::2` `64` *(**Client IPv6 Address** from HE tunnel details page)*

   [image]

   and click **Save**.
5. Click **Apply Changes** to make the new interface active.

**Allow ICMP messages**

In order to use IPv6 (and also IPv4) you need to ensure that your router does not attempt to block any ICMP packets. If some security expert tries to tell you that responding to ICMP packets is a security risk and they should be blocked, gently pat them on the head and tell them *"of course it is".  To allow incoming ICMP packets:

1. Click **Firewall** -> **Rules**
2. On the **WAN** tab, click **+**

   [image]
3. Create the rule for IPv4 ICMP packets on the **WAN** interface:

   - **Action**: Pass
   - **Interface**: WAN
   - **TCP/IP Version**: IPv4
   - **Protocol**: ICMP
   - **Description**: Allow all IPv4 ICMP packets
   - Click **Save**

   [image]
4. Click **`+`** to add another rule, this time to allow all IPv6 ICMP traffic on the **WANv6** interface:

   - **Action**: Pass
   - **Interface**: WANv6
   - **TCP/IP Version**: IPv6
   - **Protocol**: ICMP
   - **Description**: Allow all IPv6 ICMP packets
   - Click **Save**

   [image]
5. Click **Apply Changes** to apply your changes

**Enable IPv6 on the pfSense LAN**

Now you have to give the pfSense box an IPv6 address on your LAN interface. Just like it has a `192.168.1.1` IPv4 address on the LAN, now you need an IPv6 address. Except this address comes from Hurricane Electric; it is the **Routed /64** address they give you.

1. Click **Interfaces** -> **LAN**
2. Change **IPv6 Configuration Type** to **Static IPv6**
3. Under the **Static IPv6 configuration** section, enter the routed /64 address provided by tunnelbroker:

   [image]
4. Click **Save**
5. Click **Apply Changes**

**Enable DHCPv6 Server**

In order for clients to get IPv6 addresses, you have to enable the DHCPv6 server, and give it an address range it can assign addresses from.

1. Click **Services** -> **DHCPv6 Server/RA**
2. Check the **Enable DHCPv6 server on LAN interface** checkbox to reveal configuration options
3. In the **Range** from and to boxes, enter some range of addresses that are inside your **Available Range**, e.g.

   > Range: `2001:470:1f:b34::100:0` to `2001:470:1f:b34::100:fff`

Comment: i never got to finish the steps and the screenshots. i came across a bug that causes pfSense to endlessly reboot without any way to recover except wipe the hard-drive. pfSense 2.1 doesn't support IPv6 fully anyway (traffic shaping); so i switched to monowall beta. It doesn't support IPv6 either (traffic shaping).

Comment: It might be nice to note this at the top of your post so people don't get disappointed when your instructions peter out.